# Are there any restrictions to voting?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I navigate through this website I can't keep myself from voting some beautiful algorithms or codes or questions, but I am always afraid of being blocked or punished somehow because of this. But, just to be clear, are there any rules for counting how much someone is voting?

Comment: Down voting is not an answer.

Comment: As a matter of fact, on meta, it is. Don't ask me why, it just is.

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131314/248731

Comment: Yes, you can't upvote all of your friend's posts.  Yes, you will get in trouble for this.  Yes, they will know.  Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we can't see any individual votes you cast, nor would we care if you voted for a bunch of different things by different people.

The only cases where we step in are where there's clear vote coordination between specific accounts to artificially boost the reputation of another. We have good enough tools to pick that out from normal voting patterns and can look for obvious connections between accounts.

Beyond that, you're free to vote how you want.